# angularjs drag and drop index not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-table

I want to  be able to drag and drop table rows and having the element rearranged and the index updated in the model

I've found an example on stackoverflow, but it doesn't seem to work properly as the index doesn't update after a drag and drop.

HTML

```
<div ng:controller="controller">
    <table style="width:auto;" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Index</th>
                <th>Count</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ui:sortable ng:model="list">
            <tr ng:repeat="item in list" class="item" style="cursor: move;">
                <td>{{$index}}</td>
                <td>{{item}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <hr>
    {{list}}
</div>

<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
```

JS

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui']);

myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
  $scope.list = ["one", "two", "thre", "four", "five", "six"];
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
```

This is the link to fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/SSSUUUSSS/Bsusr/1/

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi. I tested and the column index of the table is changed correctly after the drag & drop.

Comment: Ricardo Rocha, really? for me it only works from down to up. If I drag and drop a row from the uppers rows to ower. It doesn't work. The index remains the same. Is it possible that it is due to jsquery/angular versions? I am using angular 1.5.5 and Jquery ui 0.40.-3 and jquery 3.2.1

Comment: I'm testing using the jsfiddle.net link that you posted and it is working down to up and up to down

Comment: Very strange. The drag and drop works too for me..but only the index doesn't work. It keeps showing 0

Comment: Try to clean the site data and run again the js file

Comment: clean the site data? Not sure I understood. How do I do that Ricardo?

Comment: Check out this link https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en